# Retrofit getBodyAs() fails to parse server error

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to parse server message which is sent when something went wrong. Message is sent in JSON:

```
{
    "Message" : "readable reason",
    "Id" : 0, // reason code
}
```

Model class for error:

```
public class RetrofitError
{
    private String message;
    private int id;
}
```

Retrofit is created with this code:

```
RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder();

builder.setLog(new AndroidLog(LOG_TAG));
builder.setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL);
builder.setEndpoint(Constants.getUrl());
builder.setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor);

GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting();

Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

builder.setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson));

RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();
```

And the error retrieving:

```
RetrofitError error = (RetrofitError)retrofitError.getBodyAs(RetrofitError.class)
```

It works without exceptions, so it seems that I'm doing something like correct. But it constantly fails to parse both fields in the response. Retrofit is created only once, and it successfully retrieves and parses all server responses with except of an error one.

I'm using latest available Retrofit jar - 1.4.1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The JSON has uppercase field names but your Java class has lowercase. By default, Gson is case sensitive.

Comment: @JakeWharton
Yes, I also thought about it and I've tried to make field names to be exactly the same as in JSON, but it didn't help.

Comment: `@SerializedName("Message")` didnt help?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this if you are still facing this issue. I know this is a very old question but it might help others.

```
    if (restError != null)
        failure(restError);
    else
    {
        failure(new RestError(error.getMessage()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple Solution with `getBodyAs` to get a JSON Object.

```
JsonObject responseAsJson = (JsonObject) retrofitError.getBodyAs(JsonElement.class);

String  message = responseAsJson.get("Message").getAsString(); //=> "readable reason"
Integer      id = responseAsJson.get("Id").getAsInt();         //=> 0
```

Confirmed working in Retrofit 1.x. Not sure what changes are required for Retrofit 2.x.